# When can we say that each open set in $U_1 \subset X$ contains another open set $U_2 \subset U_1$ s.t. $U_2 \neq U_1$

Tags: general-topology

As written in the title . Given a topological space $X$, what are the conditions required if we want to be able to say that each nonempty open set $U_1 \subset X$ contains another nonempty open set $U_2 \subset U_1$ s.t. $U_2 \neq U_1$?

And also, when can we say that for each open set $U_1 \subsetneq X$, there is an open set $U_2$ such that $U_1 \subsetneq U_2 \subsetneq
 X$?

Thank you!

Comment: You probably want to say that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are nonempty in your first paragraph.

Comment: yes thank you I will add that

Comment: Two quick observations which aren't answers. For the first, note that this means that there are no minimal nonempty open sets, in particular no point has a smallest neighbourhood.  For the second, note that this is equivalent to the family of nonempty closed sets having no minimal elements, and so such a space cannot be T$_1$.

Comment: Following up on @ArthurFischer's comment: Define a preorder on $X$ by $x\le y$ iff $\overline{\{x\}}\supset\overline{\{y\}}$. Then $X$ has the second property if and only if for every $x$ there is a $y$ with $y\ge x$ and $x\not\ge y$.

Comment: About your answers, note that the space $\mathbb R$ ,with the topology generated by open segments as a basis, satisfy the two conditions I have mentioned. Also, I think that a perfectly normal space, which is also T1 should satisfy them.

Comment: Shir, $\mathbb R$ does not have the second property. Just consider $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: you are right, of course. Thank you!